# Relatively positioned <div> preventing absolutely positioned elements from displaying with no apparent overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this page: [Image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrzBO.png) the lines on the left are supposed to be behind (or on top of, I don't care) the  text box. The lines go all the way to the top of the page when I turn up their z-index, so I am not sure how the div manages to cover them up when its size is only that of the red box.

The html, body section is what is causing my problem. See the answer below for what I actually want to happen. The thing is, I can not remove that without it making my navigation bar not sit in the right spot on the screen.

```css
        html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #e7e3d7;
  }

    .headerLarge {
        padding-top: 1.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: red;
      
      }
      
      .spine {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0;
        bottom: -15px;
        left: 50%;
        border-left: 20px solid #cdcabf;
      }
    
      .page {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: -15;
        z-index: -1;
        height: 100%;
        border-left: 4px solid #cdbfbf;
        
      }
```

```html
 <span class="page" style="left: 0px; top: 0;"></span>
    <span class="page" style="left: 10px;"></span>
    <span class="page" style="left: 20px;"></span>
    
    <span class="spine"></span>
    
    <span class="page" style="right: 0px;"></span>
    <span class="page" style="right: 10px;"></span>
    <span class="page" style="right: 20px;"></span>
    
    <span class='headerLarge'>Doodle of the Day!</span>
```

Comment: is there a reason why are you using all span? so exactly what do you want to happen to your page?

Comment: @Crystal I was using all <p> until I decided that that might be the issue, tried div and span and nothing changed so I just left it at span. What I want to happen is what AStombaugh 's code does below, though somehow mine does not function the same as his when I copy it. Now I assume that somewhere in the large amount of other code I have is causing the issue, though I don't know where to look and posting that much code would be too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated per comment:

```css
.headerLarge {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0 16px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.spine {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 20px solid #cdcabf;
}

.page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -15;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 4px solid #cdbfbf;
}
```

```html
<span class="page" style="left: 0px; top: 0;"></span>
<span class="page" style="left: 10px;"></span>
<span class="page" style="left: 20px;"></span>

<span class="spine"></span>

<span class="page" style="right: 0px;"></span>
<span class="page" style="right: 10px;"></span>
<span class="page" style="right: 20px;"></span>

<span class='headerLarge'>Doodle of the Day!</span>
```

Comment: Seemingly the z-index is not the problem. Changing z-index only served to make the div disappear. Since your code works perfectly, I assume there must be some weird error hidden elsewhere. If you look at my image, the div covers up the lines all the way to the right when it is nowhere near them. Any idea how it could be doing that?

Also, specifying relative for .headerLarge doesnt change anything except make the background of the div larger and partly cover the navbar

Comment: @AuWiMo Well, you don't have a margin defined on the header so that could be part of it? See my updated answer. Also, consider looking into flexboxes for doing layouts because the way you're doing it is probably making your life a lot harder than it needs to be ;) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: margin definitely didnt fix it. I will go check out flexboxes. I have messed with them before in a tutorial for making my navbar but I dont actually know what they are lol. Thanks for the help and the link!

Comment: @AuWiMoc i know you’ve put work into this but I genuinely think starting over with a proper flex layout and layering your elements is the best course of action. I think it’ll just make your life easier and in the end you’ll arrive at your goal. Plus we’re all here to help when you get stuck! :)

Comment: @AuWiMo Glad I could help, and yes please don't use answers for comments ;) Once you've gotten your new work put together if you get stuck please feel free to ask another question or take a look at some flexbox examples on the web so you can see just how powerful they are! :) Happy coding!